# Django/ HTML: Read more doesn't work on a main blog page

Tags: html, django

I am developing locally django page and have some issues when I click on "Read more" button.

For post called "test" it is working fine, I putted there random text.

for posts: "Projekty: API do spradzania pogody 2" and "Projekty: API do spradzania pogody " it doesn't work. I putted inside some yt links .When I click o "Read More" nothing happens. Also when I hover over button no link is shown. Do you know why I cannot click there?

[image: read more]

index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} 
{% block content %}
<style>
    body {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        background-color: #fdfdfd;
    }
    
    .head_text {
        color: black;
    }
    
    .card {
        box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
    }
</style>

<header class="masthead">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-md-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="site-heading">
                    <h3 class=" site-heading my-4 mt-3 text-black"> Welcome to my awesome Blog </h3>
                    <p class="text-light">We Love Django As much as you do..! &nbsp
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
        <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 left">
            {% for post in post_list %}
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on}} </p>
                    <p class="card-text">{{post.content|safe|slice:":200" }}</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
    </div>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

urls.py project:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
     path('portfolio/', include('blog.urls')),
     path('about_me/', include('blog.urls')),
    ]
```

urls.py app:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('portfolio/', views.Portfolio.as_view(), name='portfolio'),
    path('about_me/', views.Portfolio.as_view(), name='about_me'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),


    ]
# to jest dla wysiwyg
  # add condition in django urls file

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

viewing page source:

```
  <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">Projekty: APi do sprawdzania pogody 2</h2>
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6">marcin | Jan. 17, 2022, 10:48 a.m. </p>
                    <p class="card-text"><p>To jest aplikacja do sprawdzania temperatury w mieście podanym przez użytkownika. Aplikacja łączy się z API&nbsp;&nbsp;strony openweathermap.org i pobiera dane temperatury.</p><p><span style="color</p>
                    <a href="/about_me/projekty-api-do-sprawdzania-pogody2/" class="btn btn-primary">Więcej...</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">test</h2>
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6">marcin | Jan. 17, 2022, 10:45 a.m. </p>
                    <p class="card-text"><p>agagadsfgsadgasgasdgasdg</p></p>
                    <a href="/about_me/test/" class="btn btn-primary">Więcej...</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">Projekty: APi do sprawdzania pogody</h2>
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6">marcin | Jan. 17, 2022, 10:40 a.m. </p>
                    <p class="card-text"><p>To jest aplikacja do sprawdzania temperatury w mieście podanym przez użytkownika. Aplikacja łączy się z API&nbsp;&nbsp;strony openweathermap.org i pobiera dane temperatury.</p><p><span style="color</p>
                    <a href="/about_me/projekty-api-do-sprawdzania-pogody/" class="btn btn-primary">Więcej...</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I did some testing:

- not sure why all links have this url "/about_me", this I think should be removed. Do you know how to do it?
- this url " /about_me/test/" when I hover over this it has link. When I click on it it opens page correctly. Another two doesn't have it, do you know reason?
- also all links are working when I open from web browser:

  1. 127.0.0.1:8080/about_me/projekty-api-do-sprawdzania-pogody2/
  2. http://127.0.0.1:8080/about_me/projekty-api-do-sprawdzania-pogody/
  3. 127.0.0.1:8080/about_me/test/

urls.py app updated as you mentioned:

```
path('posts/<slug:the_slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
```

After updating is same issue.

about_me.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

<style>
        .card{
            box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
        }
       img {
          width: 60%;
          height: auto;
          object-fit: contain;      
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 left  top">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text"></p>
        <p style="text-align: center;">Witam na mojej stronie.<br /><br />&nbsp;<br /><br />Uczę sie w wolnym czasie programowania. Interesuje sie gł&oacute;wne Full stack Web dev, technologie z kt&oacute;rymi mam największe doświadczenie:<br /><br />Python<br />Django<br />Css bootstrap<br />HTML<br />API<br /><br />Na stronie będę zamieszczał r&oacute;żne interesujące mnie informacje odnośnie programowania.<br /><br />W sekcji portfolio są projekty kt&oacute;re zrobiłem.<br /><br />&nbsp;<br /><br />W razie chęci kontaktu prosze o kontakt na email: marcin.idzik1@gmail.com</p>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>pozdrawiam,</div>
<div>Marcin</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Moja strona</title>
         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
            crossorigin="anonymous" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <style>
            body {
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
            font-size: 17px;
            background-color: #fdfdfd;
        }
        .shadow {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        .btn-danger {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #f00000;
            border-color: #dc281e;
        }
        .masthead {
            background: #3398E1;
            height: auto;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }
        img {
            width: 00%;
            height: auto;
            object-fit: contain; 
    </style>
        {% load static %}
               <center> <img src="{% static 'blog/moj.png' %}" alt="My image"> </center>

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light shadow" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                
                
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"
                    aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item text-black">
                            <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="/">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item text-black">
                            <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="portfolio/">Moje projekty</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item text-black">
                            <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="about_me">Kontakt</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        {% block content %}
        <!-- Content Goes here -->
        {% endblock content %}
        <!-- Footer -->

    </body>
</html>
```

portfolio.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

<style>
        .card{
            box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
        }
       img {
          width: 60%;
          height: auto;
          object-fit: contain;      
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 left  top">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text"> Tutaj znajdziesz liste mich projektów!</p>
        <p style="text-align: center;">1. Python/ API - sprawdź temperaturę <a href="https://github.com/Pr00bit/API">link</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

post_detail.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 left  top">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1>{% block title %} {{ object.title }} {% endblock title %}</h1>
        <p class=" text-muted">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on }}</p>
        <p class="card-text ">{{ object.content | safe }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

sidebar.html:

```
{% block sidebar %}

<style>
        .card{
            box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
        }
       img {
            width: 60%;
            height: auto;
            object-fit: contain;        
</style>

<!-- Sidebar Widgets Column -->
<div class="col-md-4 float-right ">
<div class="card my-4">
        <h5 class="card-header">O mnie</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        {% load static %}
        <center><img src="{% static 'blog/zdjecie.png' %}" alt="My image"></center>
        <p class="card-text">Uczę się programowania, ta strona została napisana w ulubionym frameworku Django. Więcej o mnie w linku niżej.</p>
         <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="about_me/">Więcej</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

{% endblock sidebar %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<a>` tag looks fine.
Try to view source by doing right click on your browser and select "view page source" and see what url link is being generated in the `<a>` tag on page render.

Comment: thank Ajit for info but as I am beginner I am not sure what to do after opening console. Any chance you can provide some steps?

Comment: Don't open console.
Simply right click on your webpage and select "view source" or "view page source" and then add that code to your question as an update.

Comment: I have opened page as you mentioned view source" or "view page source", now I can see whole HTML from and not sure what to do now, as I cannot see any buttons?

Comment: add that code to your question so i can look at it. 
and while you're at it, it would be great if you could also show me the urls.py file.

Comment: I added urls. so that code you mentioned where to add?

Comment: edit your question and add it there.

Comment: i added urls already for app and project.

Comment: Your slug url needs to look something like this:
path('posts/<slug:the_slug>/', views.post_detail_view, name='show_post'),

Comment: hi Ajit, I have updated post also with result of "view source" and modified that url you mentioned. I included latest testing information on line" I did some testing". Please check if possibile.

Comment: hi @Pr0bitMarcinIdzik. sorry for the late reply, i have been super busy in the past couple of days. i saw what you posted on the view source and quickly my attention went to a wrong syntax in one of your html tags. you need to change that. 
Change the following:
<p><span style="color</p>
to:
<p><span style="color: 'black';"></p>

Comment: hi Ajit. no issue thanks for information although I cannt find tjat tag you mentioned in code for example index index hrml.  That tags are from "View page source" , not sure how to find them in code?

Comment: Look into the Templates folder of your django project directory.

Comment: I went through all templates and unfortunately I cannot find it, or maybe I am blind :).  attached all templates.

Comment: maybe anyone else can help?